# MySQL Error Number. 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE `smdonation`, `SM_USERLOGIN` {
    `SM_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT, 
    `SM_USERNAME` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_NAME` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_AGE` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT, 
    `SM_EMAI`L VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY(SM_ID) 
} ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When trying to create the above table, I get the below error:

> MySQL Error Number. 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `SM_USERNAME` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ", `SM_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(20)' a line 2

Initially I tried with `TYPE=InnoDB` that failed, so search in internet and I replace to `ENGINE=InnoDB` to create the table, but the error still exist.

The error in the screenshot:

[image: The error]

Comment: But what statement produced this error? Without seeing it, attempting to help you would be guesswork at best.

Comment: A 1064 error is simply a syntax error in the code.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `smdonation`, `SM_USERLOGIN` {
`SM_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT,
`SM_USERNAME` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
`SM_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
`SM_NAME` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
`SM_AGE` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`SM_EMAIL` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
PRIMARY KEY(`SM_ID`)
}
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: ERROR message : 
MySQL Error Number. 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `SM_USERNAME`VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ", `SM_PASSWORD`VARCHAR(20)' a line 2

Comment: 3 Issues in your code: (1)You missed the Default values for `integer` (2) The table name should not contain the comma, it should be `schemaname`.`tablename` (3) Table creation should contain the parenthesis `(` and not `{` .Working code is: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/574033ec75622d63ecad0b00

Comment: Thanks Arulkumar, it's work fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Issues in your code:

1. You missed the Default values for integer
2. Table creation **should not** contain the comma in it, it should be `schemaname.tablename`
3. Table creation should contain the parenthesis `(` and not `{`

---

So your working code would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `smdonation`.`SM_USERLOGIN` (
    `SM_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `SM_USERNAME` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_NAME` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `SM_AGE` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `SM_EMAIL` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY(SM_ID) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```